# jQuery ellipsis based on available space

Tags: javascript, jquery, ellipsis

I want to be able to ellipsis text based on how much space is available.  Currently I have to provide the maximum number of characters I want to my ellipsis function but it would be far better if it did it based on available space.

How can I achieve this?

```
function ellipsisText(object, maxLength, ellipsistooltip) {
    var grace = 3;
    var text = object.text();
    if (text.length - grace > maxLength) {
        var etext = text.substring(0, maxLength);
        etext += "...";
        object.text(etext);

        if (ellipsistooltip) {
            object.addClass("tooltip");
            object.attr("tooltiptitle", text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum... I read a bout a jquery plugin a few months ago doing exactly this. I found it back googling "Jquery ellipsis", it was the second result. It's called [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) seems to work fine, but never used it myself. Enjoy

Comment: Dotdot looks great but not available for commercial projects, thanks

Comment: Well, all you've got to do to use it in a commercial project is donate something, without minimum...  even if you manage to code this in a few hours, that would probably cost more than a decent donation... Anyway good luck with your search